# Guice interceptor invoked twice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

If I have an annotation which is

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface RESTMonitor {
}
```

And if i used it on both class level and method level in the same class. Then how do I restrict it to execute only once. Now it is getting invoked twice.

Comment: What do your `bindInterceptor()` calls look like?

Comment: `bindInterceptor(Matchers.annotatedWith(RESTMonitor.class), Matchers.any(), new RESTMonitorMethodInterceptor());
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(),Matchers.annotatedWith(RESTMonitor.class), new RESTMonitorMethodInterceptor());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two `bindInterceptor()` calls, and this normally results in two different interceptors being invoked.  But if you pass the same interceptor to both calls, they will get de-duplicated:

```
RESTMonitorMethodInterceptor interceptor = new RESTMonitorMethodInterceptor();
bindInterceptor(Matchers.annotatedWith(RESTMonitor.class), Matchers.any(), interceptor);
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(RESTMo‌​nitor.class), interceptor);
```

(I [implemented](https://github.com/google/guice/commit/35023b810b1b769daa2ca191ddb4cfcea33f077f) this feature.)